# How to check if there is a selected row -Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Currently i'm working on the jqgrid,
 where I have to find out if there is a selected row.
I have a button, not edit button, and I have to know if any row is selected
Needed some one help here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put more info here ?!!!

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
 var selRow = jQuery("#List1").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
 var count = selRow.length;
  if(count > 0)
  {
    alert("Yes there is a SELECTED row found.");
  }
```